# Mixing C and ASM, cortex M4

Tags: c, assembly, cortex-m

I'm trying to mix C code and asm using a cortex M4 processor (I bought an Atmel SAM4C board).

I'm trying a simple code which doesn't work (but it does compile).

My only option for debugging is using the UART (I don't have any debugger for now).

Basically, I just want to write an asm function that do nothing (directly return to the C code).

Here's my C code:

```cpp
#include <asf.h>
extern uint32_t asmfunc(void);

int main (void){

    //some needed initialisation to use the board
    sysclk_init();
    board_init(); 

    uint32_t uart_s = 0, uart_r;

    //get_data and send_data get/send the 4 bytes of a 32 bits word
    //they work, I don't show the code here because we don't care

    get_data(&uart_r); //wait to receive data via uart
    send_data(uart_s); //send the value in uart_s

    asmfunc(); 

    send_data(uart_s);
}
```

asm code:

```cpp
.global asmfunc

asmfunc:
MOV pc, lr
```

After sending some data to the UART, I should receive 2 times the value "0". However, I receive it only once. I can assume that there is a problem on my asm function, but I can't find what.

I tried to find some doc, and I thought I was doing it right but...

Comment: You say in the comments that get_data / send_data get and send 4 bytes of a 32 bit word... yet you go on to say that you expect to receive 2 "0" bytes. U don't think this is an issue with your ASM code. It's called after all the action. Please post get_data and send_data source

Comment: Looks harmless enough. Have you tried commenting your `asmfunc()` call and see if you get the 2 zeroes then? Have you tried adding an endless loop so `main` doesn't return? Maybe you return sooner than the data can be sent and then the cpu is halted or something.

Comment: I think it is possible that the call might not happen due to optimization as it is clear that there is no need to call the func. Do you see the call in actual assembly?

Comment: @Greycon I think OP means he expects to receive the two 0s his program transmits to the terminal, since he sends one 0, calls his asm function, and then sends another 0. Since the terminal only received one 0, OP concludes the asm function did not return.

Comment: Doh, I missed the second send_data after the asm call. It's friday :-)

Comment: I don't know this processor, but a quick read suggests that LR (Link Register) "receives the return
address from PC when a *Branch and Link* or *Branch and Link with Exchange* instruction is executed." Should you be moving the SP to PC?

Comment: @greycon&WeatherVane Indeed,  Yeah sorry for using the word "byte", Weather is right.

It' not about asm optimization (I also tried to do something in the asm function).

I'll keep on searching on monday, thanks for all your answers !

Answer (score 2):

```
asmfunc:
MOV pc, lr
```

This is ARM assembly, not Thumb assembly. You're not assembling this in Thumb mode, which is causing the generated code to be invalid for a Cortex-M CPU.

Set the assembler to Thumb mode and use appropriate operations:

```
.thumb
.syntax unified

.global asmfunc
asmfunc:
    bx lr
```

Comment: Thanks for help, I will be able to try this on monday. I think I already try what u tell me but I'll do it anyway !

Comment: It still doesn't work with your code. I still don't receive the second "0". FYI, I'm using atmel studio 6.2 as IDE. Could it be some linkage problem during the compilation (compilation still work with your code) ?